# Have a standalone layer to access Database

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

If I have multiple applications, each access its own database via direct JDBC call, or via Hibernate, does it make sense to have another layer of objects which read requests from applications, return results if found in this layer, if not found, go to the database to retrieve it, acting like a cache? This new layer also takes write requests from applications and update the DB accordingly, then its own cache. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a discussion site.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn what is on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, Oracle databases communicate with each other via database links. Suppose that you create a new database (or a schema in one of existing ones, which would then be used by all your applications).

In order to collect data from all of them, you'd create previously mentioned database link and create views that select data from different sources. Those views would utilize the UNION (ALL) set operator. Note that, if you access a large data set, views over database links promise to be dead slow.

Alternatively, you might create materialized views and refresh them either on demand, or scheduled.

Pros and cons: if you use views, you can read (slow?) and write data (via instead of triggers). If you use materialized views (MV), you can read (fast, as MVs can be indexed) but you can't write into them because next refresh will make those changes disappear.

On the other hand, if that new "layer" (as you call it) doesn't *merge* data from different databases but is used in a way that 1 existing database = 1 new layer, then I don't see any benefit in doing that. In that case, perhaps you should rather pay attention to performance tuning in existing databases (are tables indexed, are statistics regularly collected, etc.).

Comment: Oracle documentation (you'll find it on OTN). Search for keywords you identify in my previous message.